# code-push whoami and code-push logout breaking job in gitlab pipeline if already logged out

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, code-push

I would like to be able to call `code-push logout` before calling login with a specific key within a stage of my gitlab pipeline. If the runner is already logged out I get an error: `[Error]  You are not currently logged in. Run the 'code-push login' command to authenticate with the CodePush server.` that fails my job. Is there any way I can invoke this command without failing the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code-push` cli doesn't have this functionality to disable Errors. You could use appcenter cli(https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-cli) with the same functionality. There is `--quite` filed which disable all errors for CI or other tasks.